# Computing $\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n^3-n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I don't understand why I can't get the telescopic sum after the partial fraction decomposition:

$$\frac{1}{n^3-n}= \frac{1}{n(n-1)(n+1)}=\frac{-1}{n}+\frac{1}{2(n-1)}+\frac{1}{2(n+1)}=\frac{-1}{n}+\frac{n}{(n-1)(n+1)}.$$

I have $\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n^3-n}=\phi(n+1)-\phi(0).$

The answer should be $1/4$.

Comment: Please provide more details, for instance, what are your thoughts about the question, what you have tried, where you are stuck.

Comment: Rewrite the $\frac{-1}{n}=\frac{-1}{2n}+\frac{-1}{2n}$ in the middle ... it is telescopic !

Comment: A telescope series is of the from $a_i - a_{i+d}$.  Yours is of the form $a_{n} + b_{n-1} + b_{n+1}$.  The $a_i$ don't seem to bear any relation to the $b_i$ terms and because you add the $b_i$ terms they compound rather than telescope.  But if you do as Donald Splutterwit suggests you note $a_n = -2b_n$ so you actually have $(b_{n+1} - b_{n}) - (b_n - b_{n-1}$ which does telescope.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:  We have

$$\frac{1}{n(n+1)(n-1)}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{n(n-1)}-\frac{1}{n(n+1)}\right)$$

and the sum telescopes.

Answer (score 3):

If you had stopped at the ${-1\over n}+{1\over2(n-1)}+{1\over2(n+1)}$ and rewritten it as

$${1\over n^3-n}={1\over2}\left({1\over n-1}-{1\over n} \right)-{1\over2}\left({1\over n}-{1\over n+1} \right)$$

then the series *does* telescope.  Note, however, you need the sum to start at $n=2$ rather than $n=0$, since $1/(n^3-n)$ is undefined for $n=0$ and $n=1$. (An edit to the OP corrected the starting point while I was posting this answer.)   The only term that remains after the telescopic cancellations is

$${1\over2}\left({1\over2-1}-{1\over2}\right)={1\over4}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum _{ n=2 }^{ \infty  } \frac { 1 }{ n^{ 3 }-n } =\sum _{ n=2 }^{ \infty  } \frac { 1 }{ \left( n-1 \right) n\left( n+1 \right)  } =\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \sum _{ n=2 }^{ \infty  } \left[ \frac { 1 }{ \left( n-1 \right)  } +\frac { 1 }{ \left( n+1 \right)  } -\frac { 2 }{ n }  \right] =\\ =\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \sum _{ n=2 }^{ \infty  } \left[ \frac { 1 }{ \left( n-1 \right)  } -\frac { 1 }{ n } +\frac { 1 }{ \left( n+1 \right)  } -\frac { 1 }{ n }  \right] =\color{red}{\frac { 1 }{ 4 }}  $$

Comment: How can you separate $\sum _{n=2}^\infty\frac1n$ from the rest when this sum is infinite? The same comment applies to the other sums. The third expression in your answer evaluates to $\frac12(\infty+\infty)-\infty$.

Comment: @Théophile:Thanks for replying;I don't understand the fact that if the sum is infinite so we cannot separate  the terms

Comment: @mezzaluna Consider, for example, $\sum _{n=1}^\infty1$, which is infinite. So an expression like $\sum _{n=1}^\infty1 - \sum _{n=1}^\infty1$ is not well defined, because it is $\infty-\infty$. On the other hand, $\sum _{n=1}^\infty(1-1) = \sum _{n=1}^\infty0 = 0$. So we have to be very careful when separating components of infinite sums.